# Why do we define dependence on variables as a linear combination instead of a product?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

If we have variables $X$, $Y$ and an outcome $O$ depends on them, why do we model it with $O = w_1X + w_2Y$ instead of $O = w_1Xw_2Y$? I recently described an outcome as the product of two weighted variables like $O = w_1Xw_2Y$ and thought "wait, isn't this kind of thing supposed to be a linear combination, am I doing something wrong?". I understand that $O = w_1Xw_2Y = w_1w_2XY = wXY$ but we can determine $w$'s factors $w_1$ and $w_2$ separately can't we? Should it be the best of both worlds $O = w_1X + w_2Y + w_3XY$? I would also appreciate a reference to where I can learn more about the general theory about these kinds of things.

For example, the outcome might be a person's decision, the variables may be different kinds of observations they made, and the weights/coefficients are psychological factors that determine how these kinds of observations lead to decisions. I thought a product $w_1Xw_2Y$ would be a good way to model it and don't understand why I should use a linear combination $w_1X + w_2Y$ instead.

Comment: Are you talking about typical linear models in statistics or probabilistic models where products are more common? Some clarification might help.

Comment: @kurtosis I'm not really sure, but I updated the question with a practical example of what I'm trying to model.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, statistical models are linear in the terms. This is not because all phenomena are linear; rather, it is because linear models are simple and intuitive. once we introduce randomness, intuition becomes much more helpful. Furthermore, linear models can be thought of as first-order approximations to the true relationship between $O$, $X$, and $Y$.

As for your question about adding an $XY$ terms, that is indeed useful. Models which include these *interaction* terms are important in many areas. If you know about drug interactions, then you can imagine how clinical trials include these interactions to assess how other factors might change a drug's efficacy.

My personal favorite reference for linear models is Weisberg's *Applied Linear Regression* (now in its fourth edition). Weisberg is intuitive and well-paced, especially for self-study.

Comment: If from my intuitions about the process I'm trying to model, it makes more sense to use a product, is there a good reason for me to change it to a linear combination since it's more common? Do you have a reference that gives a general taxonomy and talks about all the different kinds of possible models?

Comment: It sounds like you could use a linear model if you transform your dependent variable. So take logs of both sides and *voila!* you have $\log(O) = \tilde{w}_1 \log(X) + \tilde{w}_2 \log(Y)$. That is not unusual and there are ways to even let the data suggest appropriate transformations (though theory-based reasoning is always welcome). Weisberg discusses transformations.